# Is this algorithm possbile? Randomizes execution times within a fixed time period

Tags: java, algorithm, testing

I'm churning my brains trying to think of a simple way (algorithm) for the following scenario:

I wish to run some tests for 24 hours. 
There are 3 kinds of test.
Each test must be executed a certain percentage of the time.
Each test must take a random length of time to complete.

Now, if I exclude the last part - random time length - and FIX the length of time for each test then everything is fine. But with a random test time, how can I ensure that indeed the correct number will be executed in 24 hours? Seems to me like I need to know in advance the length of time for each test so that I can work out many tests in total I need!

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the randomized time length bound by any interval? If not it seems like you can't do anything, because any test may take over 24 hours to complete.

Comment: When you say each test must be executed a certain percentage of the time is that number of times the test is executed must be a certain percentage, or the total time the tests run must be a certain percentage of 24 hours?

Comment: Does the order of tests have to be random? Because if not, you can just rotate test 1, then 2, then 3, then 1 again... till the end. If these percentages are not equal, but, say, 20%, 20% and 60%, you adjust the sequence to 1-2-3-3. If even the decision which test to run must be randomized, than you have a problem :).

Comment: @Mshnik - Yes, the randomized time for each test is bound (< 24 hrs).

Comment: @theDarse - percentage of tests, not time

Comment: @Gandalv - yes, the order must be random also

Comment: You might be in trouble if you are going for exact percentage then, if it just has to be fairly close use probability and asymptotic behavior, check the second code block in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I could be misunderstanding, but are you looking for something like:

```
int numberOfSecondsForFirstTest = rand(86400); //86400 = Number of seconds in 24 hours.
int numberOfSecondsForSecondTest = rand(86400 - numberOfSecondsForFirstTest);
int numberOfSecondsForThirdTest = 86400 - numberOfSecondsForFirstTest - numberOfSecondsForSecondTest;
```

This will give 24 hours worth of testing time for three different tests with second precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for percentage of time in 24 hours, Keep a running total of the total time the test has left to run and have that total be the time percentage of 24 hours you wish

so for instance one test you want to run 30% of 24 hours would be this.

```
float percent = .3;
int totalSeconds = 86400*percent;
while totalseconds > 0
{
    var timeOfTest = rand(totalSeconds)
    totalSeconds = totalseconds - timeofTest;
}
```

this will make the test run for 30% of 24 hours, and will not exceed the limit of that test.

If the percentages are based on the number of times they must be run then you can keep a running tally of how long is left in 24 hours, and do a probabilty based test, it will not be exact but it will be close over long time periods.

```
var timeleft = 86400;
while (timeleft > 0)
{
    var prob = rand(100);
    var time = random(timeLeft);
    timeLeft = timeleft - time;
    if(prob < //percent of test 1)
        //run test 1
    if(prob < //percent of test 2 + percent to Test 1)
        //run test 2
    if(prob > //percent of test 2 + percent of test 1)
        //run test 3
```

This algorithm uses end behavior asymptotes of probabllity, so it will not always come out exactly but over a period of 24 hours it should be fairly close if you limit the length of each test to small amounts of random under 1000 seconds or so